# c++ custom container compilation error

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to write a container as

```
 template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> >    
 class circular_dlist{
     ....
     public:

     class iterator{ 
       ....
     };

     void insert(T& val);
 };
```

In .cpp file when I define insert() method as:

```
template <typename T, typename A = std::allocator<T> > 
void circular_dlist<T, A>::insert(T& val){
}
```

I get following error:

```
error: default template arguments may not be used in function templates without -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

What is the correct syntax for defining function outside class definition in such cases if I am not using c++11?

Comment: Same workaround as for no default arguments on functions.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want it in a `.cpp` file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021

Comment: @MikeSeymour Thanks for pointing out .. I think I should move implementation to .h

Answer (score 0):

Write simply

```
template <typename T, typename A> 
void circular_dlist<T, A>::insert(T& val){
}
```